# Automatic height adjustment for static UITableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` and I want to set the row height for three of the cells dynamically. So in `viewDidLoad()` I implemented the following code:

```swift
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

I also implemented the `heightForRowAt` method:
(The first two cells of the first section should have a fixed height)

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        return CGFloat(85)
    } else if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return CGFloat(145)
    }

    return UITableView.automaticDimension 
}
```

This the result which I'm currently getting:

[image]

I changed the lines of the labels to 0, too and the constraints of the labels inside the cells are 0, 12, 0, 12 (top, right, bottom, left).

Does anybody know, why the cell in section 3 doesn't display the data in the right way?

**Edit:**
(How it looks after the implementation of the suggestion above)

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code for `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: I didn't implement cellForRowAt, because the static tableView is a detail view and I'm setting the label of each cell like this: labelCell1.text = delegateObj?.attr1, labelCell2.text = delegateObj?.attr2, etc.

Comment: I deleted my previous answer, let me know if this new one works for you.

Comment: You need to set `labelCell.numberOfLines = 0` (assuming `labelCell` is a `UILabel`). If `labelCell` is a `UITableViewCell`, then set `labelCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sizeToFit()` did not work for you, we are going to try something a little more involved.

The cell in section 3 **is** displaying the data the right way. This is because `UILabel`s don't automatically adjust their height to accommodate the text inside. Here's what you need to do:

**1. Create a height constraint for your UILabel** In your interface builder, add a constraint for the height of the `UILabel` in section 3's cell. Connect this height constraint to your view controller's class via an `@IBOutlet`:

```swift
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellLabelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    ...

}
```

**2. Add String extension that calculates height** I am unsure of where/when you are setting the text of the `UILabel` in question, but I know you are doing this somewhere as you have described it as being "dynamic". Whenever you do set the text of the `UILabel` in question, you now also need to change the constant of the height constraint that we made in order to accommodate this text. So, we need to be able to calculate the height of the `UILabel` based on its width and font. We can add an `extension` to `String` in order to do this:

```swift
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```

**3. Set the height constraint's constant based off the UILabel's text** The final step is to set the height of the `UILabel` height constraint we made by using the extension we just created:

```swift
cellLabel.text = "DummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyDataDummyData"
//This will be called immediately after you set the text for the UILabel in question
cellLabelHeight.constant = cellLabel.text.height(withConstrainedWidth: cellLabel.frame.width, font: cellLabel.font)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! Your last suggestion seems to be working better, but unfortunately the space between the label and the edge of the cell is far too small. But I will use a textView instead of a label instead now...

Comment: You'll have to use a similar strategy for a `UITextView`. That is, giving it a height constraint, getting its height via `UITextView.contentSize.height`, and then updating the constraint's constant. So label vs textView shouldn't be too important here. Do you have a pic of how the label looks when using my method?

Comment: Sure, how can I post it without an answer?

Comment: Did you try setting the `numberOfLines` as I suggested above?

Comment: He did. My original answer instructed him to set `numberOfLines` to `0` and call `sizeToFit()` on his `UILabel` @Koen

Comment: I undeleted the answer so you guys can see it

Comment: I edited the my question. Now it seems, as the height of the cell didn't change...

Comment: I don't think `sizeToFit()` is any more needed, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @finebel is `clipsToBounds` set to `true` for the `UILabel`? We could probably get this working if it's just a constraint issue.

Comment: @finebel: what did you change exactly? ("How it looks after the implementation of the suggestion above" is not very clear)

Comment: The issue must be that the `UILabel`'s text is being updated after the height is set to `UITableView.automaticDimension`. Can you set breakpoints both at wherever you are setting the `UILabel`'s text and height constraint constant and the line `return UITableView.automaticDimension`? You need to make sure that the label's height constraint (`cellLabelHeight`) changes **before** you call `return UITableView.automaticDimension`.

Comment: You could maybe call `UITableView.reloadData` after you call `cellLabelHeight.constant = cellLabel.text.height(withConstrainedWidth: cellLabel.frame.width, font: cellLabel.font)`? But ideally you would update the label **before** you call `return UITableView.automaticDimension`

Comment: Here is the sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/le32yhlduuq7ckg/SampleProjectFE.zip?dl=0 It would be best, if there is a solution without the heightConstraint, because I have to it for three cells...

Comment: I'll check it out. In the meantime, can you set some breakpoints as outlined in the comments above to ensure that the label's text and height constraint are set **before** `return UITableView.automaticDimension` is called? I'm confident this is the issue. Calling `UITableView.reloadData()` after setting the constraint's height could also fix it, though it's kind of hacky.

Comment: Actually I figured out, that return UITableView.automaticDimension  is called after the label's text is set. It would be awesome, if you could just implement it in the right way in the SampleProject! I'm confused now :-( ...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to say. Look at the above comments. If you call `UITableView.reloadData()` on the line after `cellLabelHeight.constant = cellLabel.text.height(withConstrainedWidth: cellLabel.frame.width, font: cellLabel.font)`, you should be good.

Comment: Awesome :) glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The cell in section 3 **is** displaying the data the right way. Unless you tell it otherwise, a `UILabel` will not automatically adjust to accommodate the text within it.

What I need you to do is select the `UILabel` in question, then in the attributes inspector, set the `Number of Lines` to `0`.
[image]

You also said that this `UILabel` is dynamic, meaning you are setting it's text somewhere in your code. Immediately after you set this `UILabel`'s text, you are going to want to call `myLabel.sizeToFit()`. This should adjust the label's height to accommodate the text within.

If this doesn't work, I have another, more involved solution that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below;

- Select your cellLabel and set the Lines value to 0:

Also apple says [Self-Sizing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html)

**Summary :**
lay out your table view cell’s content within the cell’s content view. To define the cell’s height, you need an unbroken chain of constraints and views (with defined heights) to fill the area between the content view’s top edge and its bottom edge. If your views have intrinsic content heights, the system uses those values. If not, you must add the appropriate height constraints, either to the views or to the content view itself.
Change the bottom constraint of the AuthorLabel from equal to Greater than or equal